# My Video Filesize Does Not Equal Bitrate x Time

Tags: video, cmd, command-line, ffmpeg, bitrate

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to encode some videos with h264. I'm trying to hit a target filesize.

My code is:

```
D:\SOFTWARE\ffmpeg\bin\test\ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -b:v 200k -an "%~n1.mp4"
```

The video is 15 seconds long.

So I've read that my filesize should be 200 x 15 (bitrate x duration). But it's not. The filesize is 400kb, when it should be 3000kb.

What gives?

Comment: There are difference in bits and bytes. 8bit = 1byte. Bitrate in bits, filesize in bytes. So to achieve exactly what you need multiply bitrate by 8

Answer (score 1):

It's **bit**rate, so  `200k` == `25kb`. File sizes are shown in bytes.